# Source of a HANDLE on windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, winapi, handle

I am currently working on a project (in C), in which I'm using different win HANDLE (mutex, semaphore, thread, ...).
My question is : Is there a way to retrieve the types of kernel object an HANDLE is linked to? Something like : Get_HANDLE_source() or Is_thread_HANDLE() ?

Thank you,

Cheers!

Comment: [NtQueryObject](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb432383%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) should get you what you want

Comment: Why do I *not* get warm fuzzies about using a function that is documented right out of the gate with "This function may be changed or removed from Windows without further notice." ?

Comment: this is probably an x-y problem. what is it you *really* want to accomplish?

Comment: I'm implementing an API on top of winapi, and I just want to be sure that someone is not using a thread-related function with an HANDLE to any other object.

Comment: @Al3xophis Then, you will probably not expose the handle. Rather create structs that contains the handle and add operations for each struct.

Comment: Vote to reopen. Checking the handle type for debugging purposes is a perfectly good reason to do this. C has sufficient type-safety issues that you'd want to double-check this in debug builds. And for debugging purposes it doesn't matter that much if the method is removed in future Windows versions.

Comment: You can safely call thread-related functions with any handle. The chech, you are doing is already identically done in kernel and if this check finds out, that this handle is not thread related, the function simply returns an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said NtQueryObject. But It is probably better to use some OO concepts:

```
struct HandleVtable
    {
    /* function pointer to appropriate implementation */

    };

struct HandleWrapper
    {
    struct HandleVtable *vptr;
    HANDLE handle;
    };
```

For each type of handle, create a static const HandleVtable and fill it with function pointers. When creating HandleWrappers, set vptr so it points the corresponding vtable, and let all function calls go through that vtable. For this it is best to write a wrapper function that takes a pointer to a HandleWrapper.

Now you will have OOP in C.

Comment: Thank you! Didn't think about doing that way. That could do the job :)